# `;` in string causing encoding not to work

Tags: jquery, json, cookies, session-cookies

I am interpreting some data that is coming through an input that has ; in it specifically "M-F 8am - 8pm; Sat-Sum 9am-10pm" which is cutting off my JSON and making my object break. What ways can I get around this??

```
{"id":null,"initPath":"/home","storeLocator":{"queryString":"edina"},"order":{"Store_ID":"10305","Store_Info":"7700 NORMANDALE BLVD, EDINA, MN, 55439","Hours_Of_Operation":"M-F 8am - 8pm; Sat-Sum 9am-10pm","Store_Phone":"111-222-3333","Language_ID":"4"},"orderLabel":{"Order_Summary":"Order Summary","Location":"Pick Up Location:","Hours":"Store Hours:","OC_Participation_Level_Description":"Participation Level:","OC_Type_Name":"Cake Type:","OC_Cake_Design_ID":"Design:","Shape":"Shape:","Size":"Size:","Serves":"Serves:","Price":"Price:","Tax":"Tax:","Total":"Total:","Top_Border_Icing_Color_ID":"Top Border:","Bottom_Border_Icing_Color_ID":"Bottom Border:","Decoration_Comment":"Decoration Comment:","Special_Request_Comment":"Special Request:","Personalization":"Message:","Personalization_Color_ID":"Message Color:","Upload_Image_Filename":"Upload Image:","Quantity":"Quantity:","OC_Salutation_ID":"Message:","Special_Occasion_Comment":"Comments:","Customer_First_Name":"First Name:","Customer_Last_Name":"Last Name:","Pickup_Date":"Pick Up Date:","Phone_No":"Phone Number:","Email_Address":"Email Address:","IP_Address":"IP Address:","Ordering_Device":"Ordering Device:","Ordering_OS":"Ordering OS:","Ordering_Browser":"Ordering Browser:","Store_id":"Store:","Language_id":"Language:","OC_Shape_Size_ID":"Shape Size","Back_Button":"Back","Place_Order_Button":"Place Order","Pickup_Time":"Pick Up Time:","Lead_Time":"Lead Time:","Days":"days","Image":"Image:"},"choices":{},"countryId":"US","languageId":"4"}
```

I am then storing this in a cookie which then parses it back as this when getting it back

```
{"id":null,"initPath":"/home","storeLocator":{"queryString":"edina"},"order":{"Store_ID":"10305","Store_Info":"7700 NORMANDALE BLVD, EDINA, MN, 55439","Hours_Of_Operation":"M-F 8am - 8pm
```

I am saving the JSON in a cookie with this command

```
session =  $.JSON.encode(session);
    document.cookie = "dqcakes_session=" + encodeURIComponent(session)  + "; path=/";
```

and decoding with this

```
var session = getCookie("dqcakes_session");
    session =   $.JSON.decode(decodeURIComponent(session));
```

Could this possibly be the encodeURIComponent??

I'm just using a simple parser for the JSON and it can't be that.

Comment: can you include the JSON here?

Comment: we need some code to help you?

Comment: just to clarify for future readers: The answer is now incorporated into the question.  The two pieces of javascript should be placed in the answer, not the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try url encoding the json string before placing it in the cookie.

replacing it with '%3b' manually may work also.

Comment: could you explain the downvote so I can edit my answer?

Comment: @Dan: Specifically, encode using `encodeURIComponent`, which encodes `;`, since `;` is a delimiter when setting a cookie. Decode later with `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Are there any other things I can expect from JSON as in errors like this or is this a unique one.  I'm getting a XML pull  and I'm concerned about this breaking all the time.

Comment: To be strict, this isn't a JSON error, per se.  Semicolons are valid characters within JSON.  AS T.J. Crowder said, it's a character that delimits cookies.

As long as you encode/decode the JSON data, you should be ok.  JSON is a wonderful way of doing this.

Comment: Can I use the encodeURICompenent for the whole object or just when inputting into the object?

Comment: Sorry I've just had to get into the details of this because the cookies on this app I just "enherited" is BREAKING all the time with plugins.  AngularJS is skipping my cookie saves so It's been utter hell.

Comment: I'd do it on the whole object - so when someone puts a semi colon in another field you are ready. Encode your JSON just before you store it to a cookie.   Decode it just before you load the JSON back into an object.